# How to redirect only select subdomains in HAProxy?

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, haproxy, http-proxy

I have several domains such as `abc.blah.com`, `xyz.blah.com`, `2a.blah.com`, `3b.blah.com` and many more. In my haproxy.cfg file I would like to handle only a few of the domains and leave the rest to go their intended destination.

For example:

Redirect `abc` and `xyz` to different destinations

`abc.blah.com == 10.1.1.11`

`xyz.blah.com == 10.1.1.12`

But not `2a.blah.com` or `3b.blah.com` or `*.blah.com`. Let them be directed to the actual destination.

That means `2a.blah.com` should go to `2a.blah.com`

here is the haproxy.cfg

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    contimeout 5000
    clitimeout 50000
    srvtimeout 50000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http



frontend http-in
    bind 0.0.0.0:80
    acl xyz hdr(host) -i xyz.blah.com
    acl abc hdr(host) -i abc.blah.com
    acl default hdr_end(host) -i .blah.com

    ## figure out which one to use
    use_backend xyz_cluster if xyz
    use_backend abc_cluster if abc
    use_backend direct_forward if default

# send it to xyz.blah.com 
backend xyz_cluster
    option forwardfor
    server node1 10.1.1.12:8080

# send it to "abc.blah.com"
backend abc_cluster
    option forwardfor
    server node1 10.1.1.11:8080

# handle 2a.blah.com
# handle 3b.blah.com
# handle *.blah.com
# basically forwarding to the source itself
backend direct_forward
    option httpclose
    option http_proxy


listen  stats   :9000
    mode  http
    stats enable
    stats hide-version
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats uri  /stats
    stats auth test:test123
```

With this configuration, the requests to `xyz` and `abc` are routed correctly.

```
curl -x 10.148.240.78:80  http://xyz.blah.com
```

Works fine

But requests to `2a.blah.com` are throwing 503

```
curl -x 10.148.240.78:80  http://2a.blah.com
<html><body><h1>503 Service Unavailable</h1>
No server is available to handle this request.
</body></html>
```

The haproxy log shows the following,

```
Mar 30 16:48:17 ubuntu-ha-proxy-3289 haproxy[9105]: 10.254.184.246:54533 [30/Mar/2017:16:48:17.793] http-in direct_forward/<NOSRV> 2/-1/-1/-1/2 503 213 - - SC-- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "GET http://2a.blah.com HTTP/1.1"
```

Basically the `direct_forward` backend needs to be configured to pass the requests to the source domains itself. But it is unclear how it is achieved in haproxy.

Comment: You do that by configuring backends. Normally if a request is getting to haproxy, haproxy is the intended destination and you need to configure the host the request is actually for.  How are these requests to `*.blah.com` going to get to haproxy in the first place? Also this is one for https://serverfault.com

Comment: Note that what you are doing is not correctly called a "redirect."  You are describing *forwarding* the request to a backend.  To *redirect* a web request refers to returning one of several 30x HTTP response codes to tell the browser to make a different request to a different URL.

Answer (score 3):

> Use `default_backend <backend>` when no "use_backend" rule has been matched.
>
> When doing content-switching between frontend and backends using the
>   "use_backend" keyword, it is often useful to indicate which backend will be
>   used when no rule has matched. It generally is the dynamic backend which
>   will catch all undetermined requests.

```
frontend http-in
    bind 0.0.0.0:80
    acl xyz hdr(host) -i xyz.blah.com
    acl abc hdr(host) -i abc.blah.com

    ## figure out which one to use
    use_backend xyz_cluster if xyz
    use_backend abc_cluster if abc

    default_backend direct_forward
```

Source: https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#default_backend